# Show only photos taken in camera app

Tags: camera

In the Android 5 camera app, if you browse the photos taken, there appear also photos from Whatsapp, music album covers, etc.
Can you make the camera app only display photos taken?

Comment: Different OEMs  -> different camera apps. Which device are you talking about?

Comment: I never found any camera app with such behavior, but only a Gallery app. Are you certain its a camera app and not Gallery app?

Comment: Device is Sony Z1 compact.

Comment: I press the miniature image right of the shutter button, actually I don't know which app it starts, I guess it it's Gallery.

Comment: @Firelord some camera apps just do that for browsing: opening the gallery app :) And that's what's most likely happening here, from what OP describes in the last comment. // **weberjn:** you could try installing an [alternative camera app](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_galleries) (yes, QuickPic is a good choice). Next time you press that "miniature image" you should be asked what app to use. Some of those apps can be configured for "folder mode", which might work the way you want (not tested, just thinking aloud).